# Can't retrieve data from azure SQL Server DB-Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure

I have a web-app developed with Python 2.7 and Django. My back end database is Azure SQL Server. I am using both pyodbc(4.0.17) and django-pyodbc-azure (1.11.0.0).

I am using the following settings in seetings.py

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'XXXX',
    'HOST' : 'XXXX.database.windows.net',
    'AUTOCOMMIT' : True ,
    'USER' : 'XXXX',
    'PASSWORD' : 'XXXX',
    'OPTIONS': {
    'driver': "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
   }    
}
```

While opening a connection with the database I am facing a very strange situation, the queries are running on the database but when I am trying to retrieve the data I am getting either none(fetchone) or empty list(fetchall).

I know that  queries are running on the database because I can see that the query ran on the database level and in addition when I am calling store procedures I can see that they are running, does anyone has any ideas why it is not working and I cant get the data back from the database?

```
with connections['default'].cursor() as cursor:
cursor.execute("select  Description_ from data_input_work")
  cursor.commit()
  records=cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: So,no error occurred?Just fetch nothing from db?

Comment: Yes, i did some testing and i think it related to memory corruption, lt seems that it is trying to run other cursor , is there any option to flush the memory before running the cursor ?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but failed.You could refer to this link: 
 http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2013/06/08/django-querysets/